# Java Context - how to get a java context not based on the webserver

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I need to access the jndi context from a java app that can be deployed both on tomcat and jboss.

I cannot find a single way to access it, so I write this code :

```
try{
    String webserver = getWebServer();
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("myLog");
    if(webserver.equalsIgnoreCase("Jboss")){
        logger.severe("Webserver: " + webserver);
        Hashtable<String, String> ht= new Hashtable();
        ht.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        ht.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");
        ht.put(InitialContext.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        InitialContext ic=new InitialContext(ht);
        if(ic!=null){
            logger.severe("success");/*I am getting success as output here*/
            DataSource ds=(DataSource)ic.lookup(getDatasource());
            /*this is where it's failing*/
            if(ds!=null){
                logger.severe("success1");
            }
            return ds.getConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }
    else{
        logger.severe("Webserver: " + webserver);
        // Obtain our environment naming context
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");

        // Look up our data source
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(getDatasource());

        // Allocate and use a connection from the pool
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid the ugly "if condition" and use the same lines of code for both  jboss / tomcat?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need all that JBoss stuff, it should work the same as on Tomcat. Under the hood it *is* Tomcat.